# Is class of graphs with eigenvalue $1$ of any particular importance?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

Are graphs with eigenvalue $1$ of multiplicity more than $1$, important one? Please guide me to any book or article discussing such graphs.

Comment: Simple graphs, directed graphs, weighted graphs...? In general I would say: no. Why do you think so?

Comment: I am interested in simple graphs. I was just doing some operations on graphs and noticed such graphs, so thought of its importance.